# How to get the file size on Unix in a Makefile?

Tags: shell, unix, makefile

I would like to implement this as a Makefile task:

```
# step 1:
curl -u username:password -X POST \
  -d '{"name": "new_file.jpg","size": 114034,"description": "Latest release","content_type": "text/plain"}' \
  https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/downloads

# step 2:
curl -u username:password \
-F "key=downloads/octocat/Hello-World/new_file.jpg" \
-F "acl=public-read" \
-F "success_action_status=201" \
-F "Filename=new_file.jpg" \
-F "AWSAccessKeyId=1ABCDEF..." \
-F "Policy=ewogIC..." \
-F "Signature=mwnF..." \
-F "Content-Type=image/jpeg" \
-F "file=@new_file.jpg" \
https://github.s3.amazonaws.com/
```

In the first part however, I need to get the file size (and content type if it's easy, not required though), so some variable:

```
{"name": "new_file.jpg","size": $(FILE_SIZE),"description": "Latest release","content_type": "text/plain"}
```

I tried this but it doesn't work (Mac 10.6.7):

```
$(shell du path/to/file.js | awk '{print $1}')
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you need the size in bytes? The GNU coreutils `du` command has a `-b` option that does this; the [MacOS du](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/du.1.html) apparently does not. Be careful not to accidentally feed `du` a directory name.

Answer (score 4):

If you have GNU coreutils:

```
FILE_SIZE=$(stat -L -c %s $filename)
```

The `-L` tells it to follow symlinks; without it, if `$filename` is a symlink it will give you the size of the symlink rather than the size of the target file.

The [MacOS stat](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html) equivalent appears to be:

```
FILE_SIZE=$(stat -L -f %z)
```

but I haven't been able to try it.  (I've written this as a shell command, not a make command.)  You may also find the `-s` option useful:

> Display information in "shell output", suitable for initializing variables.

Comment: If you don't have `stat` locally, see if you have `find -printf '%s'`.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, an alternative method is using `du` with `-b` bytes output and `-s` for summary only. Then `cut` to only keep the first element of the return string

```
FILE_SIZE=$(du -sb $filename | cut -f1)
```

This should return the same result in bytes as @Keith Thompson answer, but will also work for full directory sizes.

Extra: I usually use a macro for this.

```
define sizeof
    $$(du -sb \
    $(1) \
    | cut -f1 )
endef
```

Which can then be called like,

```
$(call sizeof,$filename_or_dirname)
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I think this is a case where parsing the output of `ls` is legitimate:</strike>

```
% FILE_SIZE=`ls -l $filename | awk '{print $5}'`
```

(no it's not: use `stat`, as noted by Keith Thompson)

For the type, you can use

```
% FILE_TYPE=`file --mime-type --brief $filename`
```

Comment: Note that if `$filename` is a symlink, this will give you the size of the symlink, not the size of the targeted file. Use `ls -lL` to get the size of the actual file in that case.

Comment: Nah, you want `stat`. See Keith's answer.

Comment: Gasp! How can `stat` have been around for about a decade and I didn't know about it?